# quickest method of accessing key - value pairs?

Tags: python

I hope the question is not too unspecific: I have a huge database-like list (~ 900,000 entries) which I want to use for processing text files. (More details below.) Since this list will be edited and used with other programs as well, I would prefer to keep it in one separate file and include it in the python code, either directly or by dumping it to some format that python can use. I was wondering if you can advice on what would be the quickest and most efficient way. I have looked at several options, but may not have seen what is best:

1. Include the list as a python dictionary in the form

   ```
   my_list = { "key": "value" }
   ```

   directly into my python code.
2. Dump the list to an sqlite database and use the sqlite3 module.
3. Have the list as a yml file and use the yaml module.

Any ideas how these approaches would scale if I process a text file and want to do replacements on something like 30,000 lines?

For those interested: this is for linguistic processing, in particular ancient Greek. The list is an exhaustive list of Greek forms and the head words that they are derived from. For every word form in a text file, I want to add the dictionary head word.

Comment: [ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson) and [msgpack](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack) are much faster ways to serialize JSON-like data. -- Otherwise I would use a [Redis](http://redis.io/) database.

Comment: I'd recommend doing some benchmarks and scalability tests on various serializations formats and/or data storage technologies.

Comment: Those "other programs", what are they? Other Python programs written by you, or something else?

Comment: I use the same data to process xml files with luatex, so the other program is particularly lua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less than one million entries is not huge and should fit in memory easily. Thus, your best bet is option 1.

Comment: It was "huge" when I was young :-) Thanks, your answer and DeepSpace's are equivalent, but I can accept only one, so thank you both, I will go this route.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1 is much faster than using either YAML or SQL as @b4hand and @DeepSpace indicated. What you should do though is not include the list in the rest of the rest of the python code you are developing, as you indicated, but make a **separate `.py` file** with just the that dictionary definition.

That way the list in that file is more easy to write from a program (or extend by a program). And, on first import, a `.pyc` will be created which speeds up re-reading on further runs of your program. This is actually very similar in performance
to using the `pickle` module and pickling the dictionary to file and reading it back from there, while keeping the dictionary in an easy human readable and editable form.

Comment: This is a very late reply, but still: my question was not precise enough, but you have actually managed to read my mind. This is actually what I wanted to know. I have applied your solution and was simply amazed how much faster this is than any other solution. Shows you what a noob I am... So thank you for explaining the mechanism behind it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for speed, option 1 should be the fastest because the other 2 will need to repeatedly access the HD which will be the bottleneck.

Comment: Doesn't the YAML module read the entire data structure into memory?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a caching mechanism to hold this data or maybe a data structure storage like redis. Loading all of this in memory might become too expensive.